# SQL Profiler Trace - why is function inside stored procedure listed twice as for Showplan XML and SP:Completed

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, trace, sql-server-profiler

I have probably very simple question. I've started to learn how to profile MSSQL databases and I've created a trace template.

As test I've tried to call a simple stored procedure inside which is a one call for function.

When I run the procedure and check the trace, there are listed like 7 events. However I can see events Showplan XML and SP:Conpleted twice for that function. The duration for first SP:Completed is 0, for the second is 2.

My question is, why are these events listed twice for that function, when the function itself is called only once during the stored procedure?

```
/****************************************************/
/* Created by: SQL Server 2008 R2 Profiler          */
/* Date: 10/04/2014  07:18:07 PM         */
/****************************************************/


-- Create a Queue
declare @rc int
declare @TraceID int
declare @maxfilesize bigint
set @maxfilesize = 5 

-- Please replace the text InsertFileNameHere, with an appropriate
-- filename prefixed by a path, e.g., c:\MyFolder\MyTrace. The .trc extension
-- will be appended to the filename automatically. If you are writing from
-- remote server to local drive, please use UNC path and make sure server has
-- write access to your network share

exec @rc = sp_trace_create @TraceID output, 0, N'InsertFileNameHere', @maxfilesize, NULL 
if (@rc != 0) goto error

-- Client side File and Table cannot be scripted

-- Set the events
declare @on bit
set @on = 1
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 122, 1, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 122, 25, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 122, 2, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 122, 10, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 122, 14, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 122, 34, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 122, 11, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 122, 35, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 122, 51, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 122, 12, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 122, 29, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 15, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 16, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 48, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 1, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 17, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 2, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 10, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 18, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 34, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 11, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 35, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 51, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 12, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 13, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 14, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 43, 15, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 43, 48, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 43, 1, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 43, 10, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 43, 34, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 43, 11, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 43, 35, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 43, 51, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 43, 12, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 43, 13, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 43, 29, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 43, 14, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 15, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 16, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 48, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 1, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 17, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 10, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 14, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 18, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 11, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 35, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 51, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 12, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 13, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 13, 12, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 13, 1, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 13, 10, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 13, 14, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 13, 11, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 13, 35, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 13, 51, @on


-- Set the Filters
declare @intfilter int
declare @bigintfilter bigint

exec sp_trace_setfilter @TraceID, 10, 0, 7, N'SQL Server Profiler - xxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'
exec sp_trace_setfilter @TraceID, 35, 0, 6, N'xxxxxxxx'
-- Set the trace status to start
exec sp_trace_setstatus @TraceID, 1

-- display trace id for future references
select TraceID=@TraceID
goto finish

error: 
select ErrorCode=@rc

finish: 
go
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the trace create script?  From Profiler, select File-->Export-->Script trace definition-->For SQL Server...

Comment: I created a scalar function and a proc that selects the function value.  I then executed the proc from SSMS and I see 5 events: SQL:BatchStarting (for batch), Showplan XML (for function plan), SP:Completed (for function), SP:Completed (for proc), and SP:Completed (for batch).  Do you not see the SP:Completed for the stored procedure like I did?  Is the duplicate Showplan XML the same plan (for the function)?

Comment: I am running the the SP call also from SSMS. When I do I am getting this:

Comment: I am running the the SP call also from SSMS. When I do I am getting this: 1 SQL:BatchStarting, 2 SQL:BatchCompleted (both for USE [DB_NAME], 3 SQL:BatchStarting (declaration of return_value + SP call), 4 Showplan XML (SP), 5 Showplan XML (Function), 6 SP:Completed (Function, Duration 2), 7 Showplan XML (function again), 8 SP:Completed (function again, Duration 0), 9 SP:Completed (procedure), 10 SQL:BatchCompleted (declaration of return_value + SP call)

Comment: By the way both function and sp are returning XML. And both Showplan XML for that function look same.